# Dependence of speed of sound

Tags: acoustics, frequency, elasticity, speed

Why does speed of sound only depend upon elasticity of medium and not on frequency of vibrating particles of the medium?

Comment: Or [Is speed of sound really constant?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/91753/is-speed-of-sound-really-constant)

Comment: Or [The effect of frequency and amplitude on the speed of sound](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/372357/the-effect-of-frequency-and-amplitude-on-the-speed-of-sound)

Comment: Or [why doesn't pitch or volume change the speed of sound?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256044/why-doesnt-pitch-or-volume-change-the-speed-of-sound)